# Joomla JTable Load Array and edit fields

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, joomla3.0

I see that one can use an array with Jtable load, I tried the following:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $id = $id ? $id : $app->input->get('files', array(), 'ARRAY');

    $file = JTable::getInstance('Document','Table');

    $file->load($id);
    $file->date_removed = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());

    if($file->store())
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`print_r($id)` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

But I am having no luck. I keep getting the following error:

0 - Missing field in database: TableDocument   1.

[**Documentation on JTable**](http://docs.joomla.org/JTable/load)

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that documentation link is less than stellar.  :~(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually you doing it wrong. You can load JTable with few field values, but it only returns 1 result;

Example use:

```
$data = array('id' => 100, 'user_id' => 101);
$table->load($data);
```

The code above will search for table entry with id = 100 AND user_id = 101. You cannot load 2 table entries like that.

My suggestion would be:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
  $ids = array();
  $return = true;

  if ($id) {
    $ids[] = $id;
  } else {
    $ids = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('files', array(), 'ARRAY');
  }

  if (count($ids) > 0) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
      $file = JTable::getInstance('Document','Table');
      $file->load($id);
      $file->date_removed = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
      $temp = $file->store();
      $return = $return || $temp;
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I understand, Your suggestion seem to work a lot better, only thing it, it doesn't update: date_removed

Comment: seems to work fine if i swap $return || $file->store() around.

Comment: Yeah, may be error in my answer (haven't tested in live), updated my answer;

Comment: @di3sel Let's get you earning some points over at JSX.  Please have a look at this one: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23156/12352